# How do I know the deployer of a Liquidity Pool on Raydium?

Tags: liquiditypool

I'm trying to track and create an extensive blacklist of those wallets who keeps deploying Rugs nonstop on Sol and explore the link between them before I ape on some new Token.

Whenever I go to the LP contract, it only points to Raydium Liquidity Pool V4

Answer (score 3):

The Raydium LP v4 is the Solana program (or smart contract). I'm not positive, but I suspect when a user creates a new LP they create a new LP account (e.g. RUG-SOL account). You would want to look at the genesis transaction of that LP account and see who the signer/fee-payer is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is what shows up]
Would this mean Raydium Authority V4is Solana program still? It looks like a wallet with random coins in it upon checking the address. RaydiumAuthority is on nearly every meme coin, always a top holder, so I wonder the same.